# Joining strings in lists of strings

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"abc","def","ghi"},{"jkl","mno"}}
```

and wish to get:

```
res = {"abc def ghi","jkl mno"}
```

This:

```
Table[StringJoin[lis[[i]]], {i, Length[lis]}]
```

doesn't produce the desired `" "` between the original elements in `lis`.  As always, thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html):

```
StringRiffle /@ lis
```

> {"abc def ghi", "jkl mno"}

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Riffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html)

```
lis = {{"abc", "def", "ghi"}, {"jkl", "mno"}};

StringJoin[Riffle[#, " "]] & /@ lis

(* {"abc def ghi", "jkl mno"} *)
```